# When NOT to use a React Pure Component (React.memo) and what are the disadvantages of using it wrongly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, react-functional-component

Ok, React.memo HOC mimics for a "function component" what extending React.PureComponent would do for a "class component".

If some rerendering was triggered by some parent component, pure components don’t rerender if its props haven’t changed. Ok

But i can’t understand when i should not use React.memo for function components. In my mind, it appears to be always the best solution, in a way that should be the default behavior of React components. But it isn’t. What am i not understanding of this? In which example we should not use React.memo or rely on pure components?

And if my React Component shouldn't be Pure but I made it so, what are the disadvantages?

Comment: It's just overhead, and only worth using if the cost of rendering the component is significantly higher than storing and comparing the props every time. And of course it's only viable if the parent component actually rerenders a lot without changing the props of the child component.

Comment: IMO, React rendering is fast and you should simply leave Components as it is. Only use memorised utilities when you face (feel) the performance problems

Answer (score 1):

> But i can’t understand when i should not use React.memo for function
> components.

First, let's understand when and why we should use `React.memo` and then we'll see when not to use it.

The usecase of `React.memo` comes in case you'd not want to re-render the component when the props haven't changed. So by default, referential integrity check is performed to check if a prop is changed. Now if there's a primitive type this check can be easily be performed. But if the props is `function` or `object` this comparison is not so straightforward.

For e.g

```js
var fun = () => {};
var anotherFun = ()=>{};

console.log(fun === anotherFun); //returns false
```

So when props is a function or object, if you try to compare with the previous value of it, it will return false and re-rendering will be done if you solely rely on this comparison

So this is why you almost always see `React.memo` is accompanied by `useCallBack` in the parent function that's passing the props. This is to check the referential integrity. `useCallBack` ensures that the new Prop hasn't changed and inside the child component `React.memo` compares with its previous value (through shallow comparison) and in case this is unchanged, it avoids re-rendering.

> So why shouldn't this be default behavior in React?

That's because this comparison come with a cost. In the background these comparisons and the computation has to happen which can be expensive if the gain is not proportionate.

Imagine if you use useCallBack for a method that's not too expensive in nature and also use React.memo inside the child component that takes it as a parameter. For every cycle of rendering in the parent component these computations will be performed which might slow down the performance instead of actually improving it.

Comment: And how can I measure whether memoizing or rerendering a component is the most expensive?